# Which would you say "I love sweets the best" or "I love sweets the most"?

Tags: grammar, superlatives

> 1. "I love sweets the best"
> 2. "I love sweets the most"

Which sounds more natural? Is there a small change in meaning, or am I imagining it?

Does it sound fine to add "of all food" at the end? For example

> "I love sweets the best of all food"

I think it would be better to say

> "Sweets are my favorite food"

but I'm still curious about saying it the other way.

Comment: Some people would argue that sweets are not food so the following would sound better "I prefer sweets over food".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "I love sweets the most"

sounds more natural in my opinion.
dropping "the" in "I love sweets the best" to make

> "I love sweets best"

also works, and appending "of all food" makes your sentence more verbose but does not change the meaning in any way